# Default List View Search box not working for few users in share point 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-search-box

I have a list with default view on it. The default Share Point 2013 List view Search box works fine for few users. But for some users it does not work.Means if they try to search some item with Title value the result does not shows up.Although the users having problem are able to add/edit/delete item within the list.

Please help me on this thanks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1.Please go to another list to check if this issue occurs.

2.Go to list settings> Versioning settings to confirm whether items enable content approval.

3.Please reindex the list and run full crawl then check the result.